# Система счисления (объяснить)

Tags: c++

У меня есть код.
Мне надо написать комментарии что какая строка делает, main() не надо там все ясно.
Сам код я понял, но плохо.
буду благодарен.

```
#include <iostream>

#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

// Функция для преобразования восьмеричного числа в десятичное

int vosem_v_deset(int octalNumber)

{

int decimalNumber = 0, i = 0, rem;

while (octalNumber != 0)

{

rem = octalNumber % 10;

octalNumber /= 10;

decimalNumber += rem * pow(8, i);

++i;

}

return decimalNumber;

}

int main()

{

setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");

int octalNumber; cout << "Введите восьмеричное число ";

cin >> octalNumber;

cout << octalNumber << " в восьмеричном " << vosem_v_deset(octalNumber) << " в десятичных";

return 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

да не вопрос

```
// не нужна и вредна
setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
//объявим переменную и сообщим пользователю, что нужно ввести число
int octalNumber; cout << "Введите восьмеричное число ";
// собственно введем число и сохраним в переменной
cin >> octalNumber;
// выведем это число ещё раз, а потом еще и в вызвав функцию, это же число, но в десятичном виде
cout << octalNumber << " в восьмеричном " << vosem_v_deset(octalNumber) << " в десятичных";
// завершим работу программы, сообщим об успешности.
return 0;
```

Comment: Ну спасибо, помогло, а то я не знал про это)

Comment: Время потратили на не нужною работу)

Comment: И мне уже не надо, я понял.

Comment: ну что ж поделаешь